# How to configure mysql version '5.1.49-1ubuntu8' to show multibyte charecters?

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

am using MySQL version 5.1.49 and I have not enabled UTF8 character encoding. The default character-set for MySQL is latin1. How can I change it show UTF8 characters?

Even when I query a table using Workbench I get 'NULL' in name section which I want, should display mutibyte characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

and for each table:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTableName DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

also if you will be viewing them from a webpage the HTML need this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and if you are using PHP, use htmlspecialchars() to display the values like this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($row['some_field'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

and (again only for PHP) do this after mysql_connect():

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: Will it also display/change the data that already exist in the tables in my database ?

Comment: I don't think it will fix the data that already exists - just ensure proper encoding of new data.